# How can I access XSL variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, xslt

*I have tried many methods to access xsl variable to javascript here is my code please help me to find the solution*

```
<xsl:variable name="VariableName">
<xsl:for-each select="ROW/COL/LIST-BOX/DATA">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() =1">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            |<xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<body>
<xsl:attribute name='onLoad'>javaScript:userDetails()</xsl:attribute>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function userDetails()
{
 var title = <xsl:value-of select="$VariableName"/>;
 alert(title);
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Check following code 

<xsl:variable name="VariableName">
<xsl:for-each select="ROW/COL/LIST-BOX/DATA">
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position() =1">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        |<xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<body onload="userDetails()">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function userDetails()
        {
            var title = "<xsl:value-of select="$VariableName"/>"
            alert(title);
        }
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

*found somehow...*
*xsl*

```
<table>
  <tr><td id="Rtest"><xsl:value-of select="$VariableName" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

*js*

```
 var myString= document.getElementById("Rtest").innerHTML;
```

*now it is working*